# JSPM and GIT behind Corporate proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy, angular, jspm

We are new to angular2 development. We tried some Starter projects from GitHub but they failed to install on my machine. I successfully set up NPM and TSD for corporate proxy but JSPM failed to work. I have configured HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY system environment variables on windows.Whenever i install anything using jspm, i get the following error like this.

```
Error on locate for github:components/COMPONENT_NAME
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

also for GIT i have executed the following command:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

i couldnt figure out the solution. Or is there any other way of configuring JSPM and GIT for a corporate proxy?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using [CnTlm](http://scottoffen.com/2013/10/29/solving-proxy-problems-with-cntlm/) and setting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in Windows to http://localhost:3128

Note: if you use gitbash, remember to set the environment variables there as well.